# Varying the gaps between specific bars in a D3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar chart where I want to make the gap more pronounced between the 6th and the bar in my chart and the 12th and 13th bar in my chart. Right now I'm using `.rangeRoundBands` which results in even padding and there doesn't seem to be a way to override that for specific rectangles (I tried appending padding and margins to that particular rectangle with no success).

[Here's a jsfiddle of the graph](http://jsfiddle.net/gaK9k/)

And my code for generating the bands and the bars themselves:

```
    var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                    .rangeRoundBands([padding, h- padding], 0.05);

    svg.selectAll("rect.bars")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bars")
                .attr("x", 0 + padding)
                .attr("y", function(d, i){
                    return yScale(i);
                })
                .attr("width", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d.values[0]);
                })
                .attr("height", yScale.rangeBand())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a function to calculate the height based on data and index. That is, you could use something like

```
.attr("height", function(d,i) {
            if(i == 5) {
                return 5;
            }
            return yScale.rangeBand();
        })
```

to make the 6th bar 5 pixels high. You can of course base this value on `yScale.rangeBand()`, i.e. subtract a certain number to make the gap wider.

Comment: Hey Lars,

I tried something similar, and although that makes the bar itself "higher" it doesn't change the padding of the bar (and ends up just having that bar overflow into the bar beside it) - somehow you need to find a way to recalculate the yScale (and more importantly the padding of the single bar)

Comment: Well there's no padding as such -- it's implicit in the height of the bar. So if you want more padding, reduce the height of the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function for D3 v6 that takes a band scale and returns a scale with gaps.

```
// Create a new scale from a band scale, with gaps between groups of items
//
// Parameters:
//       scale:            a band scale
//       where:            how many items should be before each gap?
//       gapSize:          gap size as a fraction of scale.size()
function scaleWithGaps(scale, where, gapSize) {
  scale = scale.copy();
  var offsets = {};
  var i = 0;
  var offset = -(scale.step() * gapSize * where.length) / 2;
  scale.domain().forEach((d, j) => {
    if (j == where[i]) {
      offset += scale.step() * gapSize;
      ++i;
    }
    offsets[d] = offset;
  });
  var newScale = value => scale(value) + offsets[value];
  // Give the new scale the methods of the original scale
  for (var key in scale) {
    newScale[key] = scale[key];
  }
  newScale.copy = function() {
    return scaleWithGaps(scale, where, gapSize);
  };
  return newScale;
}
```

To use this, first create a band scale...

```
let y_ = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(d => d.name))
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
  .paddingInner(0.1)
  .paddingOuter(0.5)
```

... then call `scaleWithGaps()` on it:

```
y = scaleWithGaps(y_, [1, 5], .5)
```

You can create a bar chart in the normal way with this scale.

[Here](https://observablehq.com/@jtrim-ons/stacked-bar-chart-with-gap-between-groups-of-bars) is an example on Observable.